# Chapter 0 and section 0 too?

Tags: counters, typography

Not sure if this question belongs here. If I start a book with Chapter 0 (`\setcounter{chapter}{-1}`), should the sections start in 0 too
(`\setcounter{section}{-1}`)? i.e. Section 0.0?

Comment: I think this is about semantics, not typography. "Chapter 0" is sometimes used as a synonym for "Introduction," etc, or as a sort of joke in a book about a programming language where the first element of arrays, strings, etc is 0 not 1. Whether you want to have a "section 0" in every chapter is a different question about the book design IMO.

Comment: Chapter 0 makes no better sense than Year 0. Fine for a joke, but not a serious option. (That said, I admit that chapter 0 probably makes as much sense as platform 0 and such places are certainly not built for humorous purposes.)

Answer (score 3):

Usually chapters and sections start with one. This is a way it could done otherwise, starting with zero for some reason (fun, ...):

```
\newcommand*{\arabicdec}[1]{\the\numexpr\value{#1}-1\relax}
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\arabicdec{chapter}}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabicdec{section}}
% ...
```

Internally, the numbers starts with one, but the numbers are shown decreased by one; effectively the chapter and section numbers start with zero automatically.